# In BigQuery, query to get GCS metadata (filenames in GCS)

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We have a GCS bucket with a subfolder at url `https://storage.googleapis.com/our-bucket/path-to-subfolder`. This sub-folder contains files:

- file_1_3.png
- file_7_4.png
- file_3_2.png
- file_4_1.png

We'd like to create a table in BigQuery with a column **number1** with values 1,7,3,4 (first number in filename) and a column **number2** with the second numbers. String splitting is easy, once the data (a column with filenames) is in BigQuery. How can the filenames be retrieved? Is it possible to query a GCS bucket for metadata on files?

**EDIT:** want to do [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files#storage_list_files-python)

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer to reflect the question of how do you retrieve GCS Bucket metadata on files.

There are two options you can have here depending on the use case:

1. Utilize a cloud function on a cron schedule to perform a read of metadata (like in the example you shared) then using the BQ Client library perform an insert.  Then perform the regex listed below.
2. This option utilizes a feature (remote function) in preview so you may not have the functionality needed, however may be able to request it.  This option would get you the latest data on read.  It involves the following:

- Create a Cloud Function that returns an array of blob names, see code below.
- Create a connection resource in BigQuery (overall process is listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-connections) however since the remote function portion is in preview the documentation and potentially your UI may not reflect the necessary options (it did not in mine).
- Create a [remote function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_function_statement) (third code block in link)
- Call the function from your code then manipulate as needed with regexp.

Example CF for option 2:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def list_blobs(bucket_name):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    blob_array = []

    for blob in blobs:
        blob_array.append()

    return blob_array
```

Example remote function from documentation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mydataset.remoteMultiplyInputs(x FLOAT64, y FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
REMOTE WITH CONNECTION us.myconnection
OPTIONS(endpoint="https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/multiply");
```

Once its in it will return the full gcs path of the file.   From there you can use REGEX like the following `regexp_extract(_FILE_NAME, 'file_(.+)_')` to extract the important information.

Comment: have you noticed files extension? it is `PNG` :o)

Comment: I did not notice that

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am not trying to query the data **inside** of any single file. I am trying to query the directory for **all file names**.

Comment: @Canovice - that is exactly the point i made mentioning the extensions. because this answer assumes the querying the files :o)

Comment: Hope G will provide some public RF codes for common use like this one, as they did for SQL UDF... I wrote more generic functions that take in an endpoint and returns a JSON string of array, which can be parsed to a list of values. You can then query any API with one single function...

Answer (score 1):

**Object tables** are read-only tables containing metadata index over the unstructured data objects in a specified Cloud Storage bucket. Each row of the table corresponds to an object, and the table columns correspond to the object metadata generated by Cloud Storage, including any custom metadata.

With Object tables we can get the file names and do operations on top of that in BigQuery itself.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/object-table-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Now that BQ Remote Function (RF) is GA as well as JSON, I thought of sharing a way to get any property of blobs in a bucket, right from BQ SQL.

!! Make sure to carefully read the official documentation first on how to set up RF as it's easy to miss a step. There are slight differences if you rather use `2nd Gen Function` or `Cloud run`

1. Create following `storage` Cloud Function (here Python) - 1st gen good enough:

```
import json
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

def list_blobs(request):
    print(request_json := request.get_json())  # print for debugging
    calls = request_json['calls']
    
    bucket_name = calls[0][0]
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    
    reply = [b._properties for b in blobs]
    return json.dumps({'replies': [reply]})
```

2. Create BQ remote function (assumes `fns` dataset, `us.api` connection and `my_project_id`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fns.list_blobs(bucket STRING)
RETURNS JSON
REMOTE WITH CONNECTION us.api
OPTIONS(endpoint="https://us-central1-my_project_id.cloudfunctions.net/storage")
```

The trick to return multiples values for a single request is to use `JSON` type

3. `SELECT` whatever properties you want

```
SELECT STRING(blob.name), STRING(blob.size), CAST(STRING(blob.updated) AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM
  UNNEST(
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(
      fns.list_blobs('my_bucket')
    )
  ) blob
```

The `JSON` is converted to an `ARRAY`, and `UNNEST()` pivots to multiple rows - unfortunately not columns too.

Voila ! I wish there was a easier way to fully parse a JSON array to a table, populating all columns at once, but as of this writing, you must explicitly extract the properties you want:
[image]

You can do many more cool things by extending the functions (cloud and remote) so you don't have to leave SQL, like,

- generate and return signed URL to display/download right from a query result (e.g. BI tool)
- use `user_defined_context` and branch logic in the CF code, to perform other operations like delete blobs or do other stuff